# What is the best way to stop execution for few seconds in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-sleep

I am new to Java. I tried to write a program to check database status (overloaded or not).

**CODE:**

```
package com.test.service;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class PersonImpl {

    public PersonService personService;

    public void InsertPersonDetails(Person person) {

        if(personService.isOverLoaded()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            //pass control to dao
        }
    }
}
```

Here I will get `boolean` from `isOverLoaded`. If `isOverLoaded` value is yes then we should stop passing control to dao for few seconds and then check `isOverLoaded` method again.

Help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Yes I tried. If db overloaded firsttime and then control entered into if condition after that what happens? could you pls explain?

Comment: it will resume your execution of code below line `Thread.sleep(5000);` or code after if condition

Comment: `Thread.sleep(5000)` pause your execution for 5 sec and resume it again. If your have any code after this statement than it will executed after 5 sec of pause.OR it will execute code written after your if/else is completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for an [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). Create a thread and as long as `isOverloaded()` returns    true re schedule the execution.

Answer (score 4):

Your code looks work fine.

```
if(personService.isOverLoaded())
{
    try {
          Thread.sleep(5000);  
          //Any other code to execute after 5 min execution pause.
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
}else{
    //pass control to dao
}
```

`Thread.sleep(5000)` pause your execution for 5 sec and resume it again. If your have any code after this statement than it will executed after 5 sec of pause if not than it will execute code written after your if/else is completed.

If you want to continue check database overload status than you need to continue execute your function `personService.isOverLoaded()` after every 5 sec to check your database status.

For Example :

```
while(personService.isOverLoaded())
{
    try {
          Thread.sleep(5000);  
          //Any other code to execute after 5 min execution pause.
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
}  

//pass control to dao
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative you could a java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue to control the flow. You would start the dao as a consumer of the queue in a thread. Your InsertPersonDetails method would then push to the queue from the main thread.

Can I also point out that it is usual in java to start methods with a lowercase letter so your method would be

```
public void insertPersonDetails(Person person)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks ok and should work. But you need to make sure that the `boolean` value passed by `personService.isOverLoaded()` is `volatile`.

`Volatile` will make sure that value of this `boolean` flag is not cached by your processing thread.

```
   private volatile boolean flag = false;

    public void overLoaded(){
       flag = true; // based on some condition
    }

    public boolean isOverLoaded(){
        return flag; // Accessed in your thread
    }
```